# Regular expression Java interpretation issue

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

I am not familiar with the following regular expression : `"!/\p{Graph}{1,}"` . How do I interpret this ? . I know the basics but was not able to find anything on p{Graph}{,1}

Comment: [*`[:graph:]` - Visible characters (i.e. anything except spaces, control characters, etc.) = `[\x21-\x7E]`*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class)

Comment: What does the {1,} do?

Comment: *1 or more occurrences*. Same as `+`.